# ksh error remove from list

Tags: solaris, ksh

I am trying to remove a certain element from a list in korn shell. It's working on my linux machine but the exact same code gives me an error on a solaris11 machine. I need a code that will work for both. It's probably because of different ksh versions but I would like to find a solution that works for both.

The code is:

```
#!/bin/ksh
MY_LIST="HELLO HOW ARE YOU"
toDel="HOW"
MY_LIST=( "${MY_LIST[@]/$toDel}" )
echo "MY LIST AFTER REMOVING HOW IS $MY_LIST"
```

On Solaris I get the following error:
syntax error at line 4 : `'(' unexpected`

Any suggestions?

Comment: I bet you have different versions of ksh on the 2 machines

Comment: Yes, I edited my post a couple of minutes ago that's where the problem comes from (pretty sure). But I don't know if there is another way to remove it, that would work for both

Comment: Can you use something like `sed -e 's/'${toDel}'//'` ?

Comment: Good question! I'm still new to bash/ksh scripting..I'll see how sed works thanks

Comment: I find ksh/bash arrays pretty annoying to work with. If you're familiar with other languages with array data types, you might want to consider that: example: `perl -e '@arr = qw( HELLO HOW ARE YOU ); $del = "HOW"; @arr = grep {$_ ne $del} @arr; print "@arr\n"'
`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, unfortunately I have to deal with bash/ksh and with different os which have different versions of everything -_-

Comment: Avoid arrays with `MY_LIST=$(echo ${MY_LIST} | sed -e 's/'${toDel}'//' -e 's/  / /')` Last sed part: replace 2 spaces by 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Melodie wrote: Finally, I used 'Walter A' solution

Nice I could help.
Enabling you to vote for me and close the question, I post my comment as an answer.

```
MY_LIST=`echo $MY_LIST | sed "s/$toDel//"`
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably need to spend some time with the [ksh88 man page](http://www2.research.att.com/sw/download/man/man1/ksh88.html).

Without futher explanation:

```ksh
set -A my_list HELLO HOW ARE YOU    # note, separate words
toDel=HOW
set --                              # using positional parameters as "temp array"
for word in "${my_list[@]}"; do 
    [[ $word != $toDel ]] && set -- "$@" "$word"
done
set -A my_list "$@"
printf "%s\n" "${my_list[@]}"
```

```
HELLO
ARE
YOU
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I used 'Walter A' solution:

```
MY_LIST=`echo $MY_LIST | sed "s/$toDel//"`
```